# Unable to use "save button (by google drive)" with data or blob source

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I would save a document to google drive, this document is created in realtime on the client side of my web app, using google drive save button, but doesn't work at all.

this is an example saving static file I've taken from there: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive and works

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

and yes simply it works,

but **if I try to set data-src with data or blob field**, it fail to save or get an error

```
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAKCAYAAABmBXS+AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAjSURBVChTY/y/7uR/BgKACUrjBSNc0f8AU/yKQAp+/vzJAABYKgl8odPr0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

**try here for "live" version:** https://jsbin.com/horopel/edit?html,js,console,output

blob is the same thing, not works, any solution? Better if Reactjs solution, but any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** [save button](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) does not support blob source.

Directly from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive) you have linked

> Requests for files on different servers are subject to Cross Origin
>   Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)) restrictions.
>
> 1.The data-src URL can be served from the same domain, subdomain, and protocol as the domain where the button is hosted.
>
> Be sure to use matching protocols between the page and the data
>   source.
>
> To serve the file when the same page is served by both http and https,
>   specify the resource without a protocol such as
>   data-src="//example.com/files/file.pdf", which uses the appropriate
>   protocol based on how the hosting page was accessed.

As you can see it must be a file.  You cant just send it a string value of the file itself.    Have you considered going though the [Google drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) directly doing a file upload of as stream?

Comment: maybe u don't understand question, the problem is this https://jsbin.com/horopel/edit?html,js,console,output read as far the end of post, the problem is how to put a data encoded 64 as link in data-src

Comment: You will probably have to save the file to the users pc or something (I am not all that sure that will work either).  You cant send data encoded as 64 to data-src its not CORS http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ what ever you send to data-src must be CORS

Comment: no, image this scenario, 1) a user draw something to canvas, 2) this canvas is converted to enc64 3)this file is saved to google drive... I hope this explain better the problem thx

Comment: I think you should try reading the documentation.   Just becomes you want to do something and doesn't mean that its possible or supported

Comment: ok I understand thanks so the solution is use Google drive api and perform an upload, I can't use filepicker to achieve this operation, right?

Comment: Probably not unfortunately

Comment: I grabbed a brief section of JS that does a basic upload to drive. This will not work out of the box. You must be authorized through Google and have the google js web client loaded. You may be able to find a more complete example elsewhere: https://gist.github.com/cowsrule/0e41eba2e31e0fc4a91141fafcaab1b9 . Another example with resumable uploads can be found at https://gist.github.com/cowsrule/c2221d76301aed6566d0aba49f9229a6 .